# Connect to SharePoint with oauth2 - Python

Tags: python, sharepoint, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to pull a file from SharePoint and copy it to an S3 bucket.
I have a code that uses a user name and password but I was asked to change my method to oauth2.
Old code that worked:

```
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientCredential

SP_SITE_URL ='https://companyname.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename' 
    
    userID= config["sharepoint"]["userID"]
    password= config["sharepoint"]["password"]
    client_credentials = ClientCredential(userID, password)
    ctx = ClientContext(SP_SITE_URL).with_user_credentials(userID,password)

    file_url = FOLDER_URL + current_file_name

    response = File.open_binary(ctx, file_url)
```

I tried to switch the credentials to clientID and Clientsecrent:

```
client_id = config["sharepoint"]["clientID"]
client_secret = config["sharepoint"]["client_secret"]
client_credentials = ClientCredential(client_id, client_secret)
ctx = ClientContext(SP_SITE_URL).with_credentials(client_credentials)

file_url = FOLDER_URL + current_file_name

response = File.open_binary(ctx, file_url)
```

but I get error 403 :b'{"error":{"code":"-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))"}}}'

I understand I need to add a layer to connect Microsoft and get a token? but I can't find the code to do it and connect between those two steps. Any ideas?

Comment: Does the user with the client credentials have the permission to read the file in the sharepoint folder?

Comment: Yes, the client has the needed permissions

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something wrong in your ClientContext Call. If you are using User/Password you should take your client_credentials object you created one line before. It should look like this:

```
ctx = ClientContext(SP_SITE_URL).with_user_credentials(client_credentials)
```

Please make also sure MFA is not enabled for your user as well as the user has permissions to access the SP site.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. But I don't want to use user credentials. I want to use client credentials. Also, I need to use oauth2 (which is not implemented here and I'm trying to understand how to do it)